# Grepping/awking assigned $variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

Is it possible to grep strings or compare fields with awk in an assigned $variable.

For example

```
grep "word" "$foo"
```

only lists the complete content of $foo.

The awk command does not recognize variables but searches for a file in my folder:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' "$foo" "$fee"
```

It says *awk: fatal: cannot open file `$foo' for reading (No such file or directory)*

@BMW suggested to provide more details. Here they are:
This is the complete command:

```
foo=$(cat my_text.txt |  grep -B5 'application' | paste -s --delimiters=" " |sed 's/--/\n/g'| awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}')
```

This is the output and the content of $foo.

- reaction_1    jj-cju  2   application
- reaction_1    jj-cju  2   application
- reaction_1    jj-cjo  2   application
- reaction_4    jj-cji  2   application
- reaction_5    jj-cju  2   application
- reaction_5    kk-cju  2   application
- reaction_7    jj-cju  2   application
- reaction_7    kk-cji  2   application
- reaction_7    kk-cji  2   application
- reaction_7    kk-cju  2   application
- reaction_7    mm-cju  2   application

Comment: run `echo $foo` , what's the output?

Comment: it shows the content of $foo which is a list of words.

Comment: a list of words? OK that's not filename. You need assign file name to variable `foo`

Comment: Sounds like you might be on a good path. This is how assigned the contend of my previous commands to $foo: **foo=$(cat my_text.txt | paste -s --delimiters=" " |sed 's/--/\n/g'  | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}')**

Comment: so why not paste some sample of content of `my_test.txt` directly , and what's in $fee as well.  The command you paste above is too bad quality. You shouldn't mix `paste/sed/awk', we should have simply way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a [herestring](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) in place of a filename:

```
grep "word" <<< "$foo"
```

This will work if your command only requires a single input file/variable. If you require more than one, like your example `awk` command, you need to use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' <(echo "$foo") <(echo "$fee")
```

The `<(...)` construct runs the inner commands, then the output is treated as if it is a file.

Examples:

```
$ echo "$foo"
first line
second line
last one

$ echo "$fee"
example
text

$ grep "line" <<< "$foo"
first line
second line

$ grep "last" <(echo "$foo")
last one

$ awk '{print NR": "$0}' <(echo "$foo") <(echo "$fee")
1: first line
2: second line
3: last one
4: example
5: text
```

Comment: Great, `<<<` and `<(...)` did the trick. Thanks @Josh Jolly for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing word search using awk then use:

```
awk -v w="word" '$0 ~ w' "$foo"
```

Assuming `$foo` is a file.

You can even use:

```
awk '/word/' "$foo"
```

Comment: I guess this is not what OP was asking... his problem is `awk: fatal: cannot open file $foo for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: But he also says `grep` command is working with same `$foo` as filename.

Comment: yes, that's the point. look at his grep and awk cmd, if the grep one expanded the `$foo`, the awk one should do too, but it didn't happen there. I guess there would be some other mistake in his codes, but don't know what..

Comment: You're right Kent, there is a mistake because the grep command only reproduces the content of the assigned variable $foo. I have tried here suggested commands - also awk commands - but the result is the same. I think I know now why that awk: fatal error occurred. I should have put my variables under double quotes. As I did it the error disappeared. The result is, however, again simply the content of the first variable.

Comment: So is `$foo` just a string variable or it stores a file name?